# QAxBase dynamicCall with pointer parameters

Tags: windows, qt, activex

i'm using an ActiveX COM Object and i have to call this method with dynamicCall

```
GetFlyerTemperature(Float* pFront, Float* pBack, Boolean bOvertemp)
```

This is my code:

```
QVariant pFront, pBack, bOverTemp;
m_wmCom->dynamicCall("GetFlyerTemperature(Float* pFront, Float* pBack, Boolean bOvertemp)",
                                    pFront, pBack, bOverTemp);
```

but i have this error:

```
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member GetFlyerTemperature: Type mismatch in parameter 0
```

Comment: You should not insert the arguments' names in the function signature when using `dynamicCall`.

Comment: so do i have to write only `GetFlyerTemperature(Float* , Float* , Boolean)` ?? but i think that the problem is the float pointer because QVariant doesn't have float pointer with type..

Comment: Try to generate the documentation for the activex using `QAxBase::​generateDocumentation()`. You can then see then the signature of all functions in the generated document.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved using this method in order to read the functions implementations:

```
m_wmCom->generateDocumentation()
```

So i have called:

```
QVariantist params;    
QVariant res = m_com->dynamicCall("GetFlyerTemperature(double&, double&, int&)", params);
```